# Application with Sencha freezes in Android

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator, sencha-touch-2

I built an application for Android using Phonegap. My problem is that in emulator application freezes at the "appLoadingIndicator". I use this command

```
sencha app build testing -d phonegapp/assets/www
```

with Sencha cmd v3.0.0.250. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a syntax issue like a missing comma.I also noticed that you are using the new Sencha Cmd. If you are still having issues, you can check out my tutorial: http://cclerville.blogspot.com/2013/01/sencha-touch-21-phonegap-220-android_3.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using the "requires" config on classes that need to load dependencies.

If you try to run the application in Chrome (on your desktop), the developer console will (usually) show warnings when you synchronously load dependent classes.

This is a frequent stumbling point for people, so it may or may not be the cause of your issue. As @cclerville points out, it could also be a syntax error of some kind.